# 2 separate objects connected via links, how to clear them

Tags: linked-data

I was messing with CTRL + L and probably somehow connected 2 separate object, now when I try to apply scale to any of them I got error "Cannot apply to a multi user: Object "Plane.028", Mesh "Plane.033", aborting". Also, when I select one and go to edit mode, it shows me edit mode of other object also. What could be problem and solution[image]
[image]

Comment: On the right side go to the green triangle (object data properties). At the top there is the name of the mesh you are using (not the object!). Right beside the meshname there is a number. Just click on it once and it is fixed. 
Ask again if it didnt work :)

Comment: Thanks! :) worked